# MRTG bandwidth not accurate

Tags: bandwidth, network-monitoring, rrdtool, mrtg

I have MRTG with RRDTool configured to monitor the bandwidth on a switch, it is set to measure the traffic in bits.
For the interface I need monitored it is showing this:

Description:    GigabitEthernet2/0/25
ifType:     ethernetCsmacd (6)
ifName:     Gi2/0/25
Max Speed:  1000.0 Mbits/s

Which is correct, it is a gigabit switch. However, on the graph it is showing 84.938Mbps out, which is not accurate, it is more like 849.38Mbps.

How do I get it to display the proper values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is counter rollover.  Make sure you are using SNMPv2(SNMP v2 use 64-bit counters).

Add :::::2 to switch definition(Target[myswitch]: 2:public@switch1:::::2) and enable SNMP v2 on switch.

Comment: Thank you, after reading your answer, I have found documentation to support this. Is it possible to get the proper values with snmp v1 (uses 32-bit counters?). The issue is that the switch is only snmp v1 capable with the current firmware.

Comment: 32-bit = 1024*1024*1024*4 = 1Gbit * 4s. You can set interval 4 second(0:4) and initial creation database, but I think it will not work.